# According to Hinduism, are all demons dead by now in the current time line or can new demons get created now?

Tags: gods, rakshasa

1. According to Hinduism, Are there any demons yet to be killed, or will get killed now i.e in the present timeline at this moment, or is there any god battling with demons now and we are not aware of it?
2. According to Hinduism, Can new demons be created now? If created which God will take care of them?

Comment: @admins may I know the reason for the closure?

Comment: Prahlada is still alive with a bunch of other asuras. Kali is alive now also.

Comment: This is a weird question, it's like asking if humans are all dead now and whether new humans can be "created" based on some humans being bad.

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa It sounds weird to you because Hinduism, with its diverse lore, traditions, stories, theologies, is very complex, especially to people who might not be as knowledgeable as you, why not encourage asking questions of all kinds, and help bridge such gaps?

Comment: @learner I guess you have a point.